# How should I use localstorage for 2 things

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I want to use localstorage to store 2 things: accounts, and products and information of it. First, I got the accounts part working using this code:

```
function signup(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    
    var user = {
        number: 1,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: pass
    };
    
    var json = JSON.stringify(user);
    localStorage.setItem(username, json);
}

function login(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    
    var user = localStorage.getItem(username);
    var data = JSON.parse(user);
    
    if (user == null) {
        result.innerHTML = "Wrong Username";
    } else if (username == data.username && pass == data.password) {
        result.innerHTML = "Logged In";
        
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
            var datas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
            var datauser = datas.username;
            datas.number = 2;
            var jsonval = JSON.stringify(datas);
            localStorage.removeItem(keys[i]);
            localStorage.setItem(datauser, jsonval)
        }
        
        
        localStorage.removeItem(username);
        data.number = 1;
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        localStorage.setItem(username, json);
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "Wrong Password";
    }
}

function getaccount() {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
        if (data.number == 1) {
            document.getElementById("accountnamep").innerHTML = data.username;
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data.username;
        }
    }
}
```

and then I have a code for my products but I dont know how I would show it in a "your cart" file but the code I have currently is:

```
                var tocart = {
                    name: name,
                    price: price,
                    size: size,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    shipping: shipping
                };
                
                var json = JSON.stringify(tocart);
                localStorage.setItem(name, json);
```

Comment: Don't create a separate local storage item for each cart item. Put all the items in an array, and store that as the localStorage item named `cart`. Similarly, put the user information in a localStoratge item named `user`.

Comment: I can do that but I don't know how to switch users using that code.

Comment: Why are you storing account information in the client in the first place? Account validation needs to be done on the server.

Comment: I need it for a project in school to make an ecommerce website using javascript so its not really that advanced.

Comment: Then do it the same way. Put an array of users in the local storage item. Or a dictionary that maps usernames to their information. Then have another variable `currentUser` that contains the current username.